# sqlalchemy datetime integers

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hope someone can help with sqlalchemy.

I've a flask application where I used standard sqlite lib and now I would like to change to sqlalchemy for better code reading and future improvements.  I can't change the schema as the app is already used by some people and I don't want that an update can cause issues.

I've some datetime column that are considered as integers by sqlalchemy and when I run a query I get the error below:

`Couldn't parse datetime string '1564598187' - value is not a string.`

I'm using declarative sqlalchemy with database module below and models.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/

database.py

```
 engine = create_engine('sqlite:///my_database.sqlite3', convert_unicode=True)  
 db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,  
   autoflush=False,  
   bind=engine))  
 Base = declarative_base()  
 Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():  
    from models import Shares  
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

models.py

```
class Clients(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'clients'  
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)  
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)  
    lastseen = Column(DateTime)  
    joindate = Column(DateTime)  
  
  
@event.listens_for(Table, "column_reflect")  
def setup_epoch(inspector, table, column_info):  
    if isinstance(column_info['type'], types.DateTime):  
        column_info['type'] = MyEpochType()
```

On models I've a few class with my database schema and then flask app where I import db_session, init_db and models.

After digging a bit about the problem I tried to apply this gist adding class and listener but it's totally ignored
https://gist.github.com/zzzeek/7470863

I'm new to sqlalchemy so I really can't understand what's wrong and how to use listener with declarative model.

As I said I can't change schema replacing datetime fields with TEXT.
I tried to dig a bit about the problem and I found this can be fixed using decorators and event listener.

That's the schema of clients table.

```
sqlite> .schema clients
CREATE TABLE clients (
                         id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                         name TEXT NOT NULL,
                         ssh_key TEXT NOT NULL,
                         status TEXT NOT NULL,
                         share TEXT NOT NULL,
                         threshold INTEGER NOT NULL,
                         joindate DATETIME, sync_status TEXT, lastseen datetime);
```

Comment: So you have an existing SQLite database with  a column that contains datetimes as seconds since the epoch, is that correct?  What is the type of the column in SQLite (`select typeof(column_name) from table_name`)?  Can you share the schema for the table in SQLite? (`.schema table_name` in the SQLite shell).  Please [edit] the question to include this information.

Comment: Looks like it's an integer even on the schema is specified as datetime.      `sqlite> select typeof(lastseen) from clients;
integer`

Comment: So before using SQLAlchemy, you were inserting integers into this column, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.   
I review my code and I used.   

    `int(time.time())`

But I guess standard sqlite lib never complained about it.   
I did that because at some point I need to calculate delta between lastseen and current time.

Comment: It might be better to use a [reflection-based solution](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapping-declaratively-with-reflected-tables) rather than declaring the columns yourself, assuming that you are happy to work with the data as integers.

Comment: I'm happy with integer but I don't undestand with reflection-base-solution how you create the database the first time. I guess I need to study a bit and probably the best solution would be to define column as integers.  My goal was to simple replace sqlite lib with sqlalchemy so an update to my app wouldn't require a schema update for existing database but I see my mistake now. Thanks for let me understand the problem.

Comment: Reflection solutions assume that the database tables already exist, and the SQLAlchemy tables / models are generated using the column details reflected from the database, rather than trying to map SQLAlchemy column types to an existing table.

Comment: A workaround I found is to use cast 

`db_session.query(cast(Events.end_ts, String)).filter_by(client=self.client).limit(1).all()`

Any reason why I shouldn't do this? :-)